# What wrong with this simple HTML Code?

Tags: html, image, imagesource

I am completely new to Web Development, still a student. Kindly bare this extremely low level question.

I have this small HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<img scr="logo.jpg" alt"nextgen logo" width="370" height="100" />
<h1> NEXTZEN </h1>
<p> Welcome to NEXTZEN </p>
</body>
</html>
```

with the logo.jpg file in the exact same folder as the .html file, with the exact width and height given.

Yet, when I open the HTML page, I am not able to see the image at all. What's Wrong? What should I do?

Comment: did you notice the missing `=` at the `alt`-Attribute? :) And the `src` is scrambled :D

Comment: Also note that you need a `<head><title></title></head>` before the body. Here is the link to the relevant section of the specification of html5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/introduction.html#a-quick-introduction-to-html

Comment: Look at Ryans answer which I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="nextgen logo" width="370" height="100" />
        <!-- fix src and add in the = on the alt tag !-->
        <h1> NEXTZEN </h1>
        <p> Welcome to NEXTZEN </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like Slicekick and jackwanders beat me to it. Should fix the problem though!

Answer (score 4):

simple typo. `src`, not `scr`

```
<img src="logo.jpg" alt="nextgen logo" width="370" height="100" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `scr` to `src` in your image tag, and add an = sign as Florian pointed out.